# QGIS slow to respond

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, windows-11

I'm having issues with my QGIS lately. The problem is I can work on it for long period again (like after 5 mins) before it will become so slow and take time to respond (at time, it'll not respond at all).
What might be the problem please.
PS: I'm using QGIS 3.28.5
Also using Windows 11 Pro

Comment: Difficult to say. Try using a new user profile: Menu Steetings > User Profiles > New Profile... and deactivate/uninstall all plugins. If that does not help, try reinstalling the current version 3.30.1

Comment: Thanks, i was actually using 3.30.1 before uninstalling everything about it and install 3.28 instead. But then, I was having the same issue even after creating a new profile

Comment: I fear that from far, its almost impossible to say whats going wrong as there could be many different causes.

Comment: Sometimes I have had to uninstall QGIS, then manually search and delete all files having QGIS in the name. There are many temp files left behind after uninstalling.